# Smooth edges in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am using [CLImageEditor](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor) for a drawing. Need to generate a PNG out of this drawing as an output. This works well but edges and the text when I zoom is not that smooth. Is there anyway I can improve this which I expect to be get an output close to a vector graphic. Here is the code chunk.

```
CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
UIColor *txtColor = self.textColor;

CGFloat outlineSize = self.outlineWidth * self.font.pointSize * 0.3;

CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, outlineSize);
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(contextRef, TRUE);
CGContextSetAllowsFontSmoothing(contextRef, TRUE);
CGContextSetLineJoin(contextRef, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineCap(contextRef, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(contextRef, YES);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(contextRef, YES);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(contextRef, kCGInterpolationHigh);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(contextRef, kCGTextStroke);
self.textColor = self.outlineColor;
[super drawTextInRect:CGRectInset(rect, outlineSize/4, outlineSize/4)];

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(contextRef, kCGTextFill);
self.textColor = txtColor;
[super drawTextInRect:CGRectInset(rect, outlineSize/4, outlineSize/4)];

self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems setting `_label.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` and `_label.contentScaleFactor = scale` can improve some quality.

Comment: This is bit old. Yes I did what you suggested and I increased the drawing context to deal with this. It worked fine for me few months ago.